# How to add my own js script to react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I have scirpt for mobile multilevel menu. How can I get it work in react? I have something like this:

```
export function mobileNavigation() {
  let navElements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav');
  let backButton = document.querySelector('.back-nav');

  navElements.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', itemClicked)
  })
  //more code
}
```

Then in my mobilenav component i have:

```
componentDidMount() {
  mobileNavigation();
}
```

But it doesnt work.. I mean I know why but I don't know how to solve it. How can I get my script available the whole time not only once when component mounts?

Comment: are you imported it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import {mobileNavigation} from '../../some address'

mobileNavigation()
```

Comment: please Approve as right answer if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers